# SASS function to convert px to em

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to implement a SASS function that will convert pixels to ems for our application and running into trouble.

Here's the function:

```
$browser-context: 16;

@function em($pixels, $context: $browser-context) {
  @if (unitless($pixels)) {
   $pixels: $pixels * 1px;
  }

  @if (unitless($context)) {
    $context: $context * 1px;
  }

  @return $pixels / $context * 1em;
}
```

and I'm implementing the function here:

```
.k-grid-header {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.k-grid-header .k-header:not(.k-widget) {
  font-size: em(16);
}
```

My issue is that it only works if I have the .k-grid-header class and I don't really understand why.  I would think the second class that calls the function would be enough to set the size.

Comment: what do you mean `it only works if I have the .k-grid-header class` ? in which scenario this doesn't work ? can you give an example that replicates your problem ? one where it works and one where it doesn't ?

Comment: there's an npm package for changing it to rem if that helps: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-rem. otherwise this seems to be the equivalent for em: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-em

Comment: What does `font-size: em(16);` generate as CSS ?

Comment: why are you converting it to pixel if it is not in pixel ? you dont need pixel for anything in this function

Comment: also what doesnt work if you dont have the `.k-grid-header` class ? everything code wise looks fine for me in sassmeister

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your function – it works with both pixels and numeric arguments. Btw I did a bunch of functions to handle unit conversion... If you are interested https://codepen.io/jakob-e/pen/AHunv

Answer (score 4):

```
/// Remove the unit of a length
/// @param {Number} $number - Number to remove unit from
/// @return {Number} - Unitless number
/// @example scss - Usage
///     strip-unit(10px) -> 10
///     strip-unit(2em) -> 2
///     strip-unit(3) -> 3
@function strip-unit($number) {
    @if type-of($number) == 'number' and not unitless($number) {
        @return $number / ($number * 0 + 1);
    }
    @return $number;
}

/// Convert value to em.
@function em($size, $base-font-size:16px) {
    @return strip-unit($size) / strip-unit($base-font-size) * 1em;
}
```

Ussage:

```
font-size:em(32px); // => font-size:2em;
```